# Call function in main thread only when worker thread is done in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am having troubles understanding how to find a solution for my problems with threads in Android. So basically the current (simplified) code below is running on the main thread and that's causing me some issues because methods `calculateMeanMagnitude()` and `predict()` are slow and hence block the UI as expected.
What I would like to do is to compute those two functions in a separate thread and once I am done call `updateData()` in my UI thread.

I am really not sure how to do this both from a syntax point of view but also how to avoid busy waiting before `updateData()` since that would also block the UI thread.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    private double calculateMeanMagnitude(ArrayList<SensorReading> accReadings, boolean isAcc) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
            if (data == null) return;

            if (data.containsKey(Constants.WindowBroadcastExtraName)) {
                ScanResult scan = (ScanResult) data.getSerializable(Constants.WindowBroadcastExtraName);
                if (scan != null) {
                    double meanMagnitude = calculateMeanMagnitude(scan.getAccReadings(), true);
                    float[] predictions = predict(meanMagnitude);
                    updateData(isStill, predictions, scan.getLocationScans());
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: [Better performance through threading](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads#java)

Comment: I recommend you to convert your code to `kotlin` and use `coroutines`

Comment: A simple solution is use **[handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui)**  to communicate UI thread and worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

Call your calculateMeanMagnitude() and predict() method in separate thread and once the both of them finished send s broadcast from that thread for updating your UI 
        register this receiver in on resume of your Activity class

```
IntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
mIntentFilter.addAction(any action string);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
```

Asyntask for executing your methods on separate thread

```
    private class Find extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, YourReusltfromthesemethods> {

        @Override
        protected YourReusltfromthesemethods doInBackground(Void... voids) {
           calculateMeanMagnitude();
           predict();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(YourReusltfromthesemethods result) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                broadcastIntent.setAction("any action string");
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("Data", "Broadcast Data");
                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And in onReceiver method of you receiver update your ui

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if(intent.getAction().equals("any action string")){
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        if (data == null) return;

        if (data.containsKey(Constants.WindowBroadcastExtraName)) {
            ScanResult scan = (ScanResult) data.getSerializable(Constants.WindowBroadcastExtraName);
            if (scan != null) {
                double meanMagnitude = calculateMeanMagnitude(scan.getAccReadings(), true);
                float[] predictions = predict(meanMagnitude);
                updateData(isStill, predictions, scan.getLocationScans());
            }
        }
    }
  }
};
```